# Ruby association: has one through many - Is it possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I want to have a strange kind of an association. Lets say I have a the following classes:

```
class Kid < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :parent
    has_one :friend
end

class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :kid
end

class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :kids
    has_one :friend, :through => :kid #This is the "problematic line"
end
```

I know the last relation(`has_one :friend`) is not possible and doesn't make sense. But lets say that I know that the Friend of the first Kid always has enough information for my Parent instance, so I want to get it like 'parent.friend' instead of `parent.kids.first.friend`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that doesn't make any sense.  if a parent has many kids, then they can't have just one friend, they would have as many friends as they had kids.

Parent.friend doesn't make any sense - the friend of which kid?

If it's always the first, make a function:

```
def first_friend
  kids.first.friend
end
```

If you want a list of friends...

```
def friends
  kids.map(&:friend)  # note this queries immediately, it is not a named scope
end
```

If you want to go the other direction to get a list of friends for a parent, use a named scope in the Friend model:

```
named_scope :for_parent, lambda {|p| joins(:kids).where('kids.parent_id = ?', p)}
```

Comment: I agree with this approach, I just had to work on a weird code where the scenario I described seemed logical :\ ... just wanted to make sure I was not missing something. Thanks anyway....